# How does Mpeg2 file plays with H.264 parser?

Tags: mpeg2-ts

I have MPEG-2 TS file recorded on my STB . VLC media information for the clip is 
Type : Video
codec: Mpeg-1/2 video(mpgv)
Type : audio
codec: MPEG AAC Audio(mp4a)
I currently do not have Mpeg2 video parser so the clip wont play at all. 
But just out of curiosity i reused the existing H.264 video parser for the above clip and the clip started playing. 
I am very confused over this. why is this happening? Is there any chance H.264 and Mpeg2 related? Is it something to do with codec and container format?
Guys please explain in detail....

Answer (score 0):

MPEG-2 TS is just the container. h.264 and AAC are the codecs.

Comment: But then why does VLC show Video codec as Mpeg-1/2 video(mpgv). Shouldn't it show H.264 ??

Comment: I don't know. I don't have a copy of the clip. It may be mpeg 2 codec in an mpeg 2 container. It may be AVC in an mpeg 2 container. I don't know what h.264 parser you are referring to.

Comment: by H.264 video parser , i mean to parse the sps,pps , slice and parsing all the stuff in accordance with h.264 spec and getting the required data for a frame to be given to decoder.. i cannot put the code here because of security issues .

Comment: Please share me your emailid so that i can send you the clip , in case you dont have any problem.